# Change DjangoRestFramework default logging format

Tags: python, django, logging, django-rest-framework

Currently, every request I send to the django app, it auto logs the same as shown below:

```
"GET /api/v1/account/test_1 HTTP/1.1" 200 5586
"POST /api/v1/account/test_2 HTTP/1.1" 201 5586
```

How can I change the above log format to look like this instead:

```
'{"api_method":"GET", "api_endpoint":"/api/v1/account/test_1", "api_status": 200}'
'{"api_method":"POST", "api_endpoint":"/api/v1/account/test_2", "api_status": 201}'
```

Comment: You have to make middleware for this. Create logmodels with your 3 fields and in middleware section record log of your own format

Answer (score 1):

The logging is not related to `django-restframework`. It is just the default `LOGGING` configuration of django.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/logging/

You can adjust the `LOGGING` of `django.request` to whatever you like.

A good starting point is the default configuration: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/logging/#default-logging-configuration

Comment: Thanks. I modified the default configuration to a different format I needed. The updated version worked fine in local, however in my k8s wsgi server it seems to ignore my format and continue with the default one. Any idea what might be the issue?